# Custom Callback Validation Function to Achieve a Custom Error Message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CI form with a field requiring a decimal number. Currently when the field fails validation the user gets an unhelpful message. "The field must be decimal". This is a poor user experience for a user that feels they should be able to use a leading period. e.g. ".4". I am trying to create a Custom callback validation function to achieve a custom error message. Here is my controller (simplified)...

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('expenses', 'Expenses',   'trim|max_length[50]|callback_decimalcustom|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
    $parent_data = array('country' => $countrydata, 'currency' => $currencydata, 'tour' => $tourdata, 'riders' => $ridersdata, 'measurement' => $measurementdata, 'tourdistance' => $tourdistance);
    $this->load->view('myform', $parent_data);
        }
        else        
    {                       
    $sql= array (
        'expenses'=>$this->input->post('expenses'),
            );
    $ins = $this->db->insert('donations',$sql);

    $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }   
    public function decimalcustom($str) //Custom decimal message
    {    
        if (preg_match('/^[\-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/', $str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('decimalcustom', 'The %s field is required in 0.00 format.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When testing, the error is not thrown, ever since I changed the validation from decimal to decimal custom. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_match() returns TRUE when it's a valid number but you're trying to throw an error. Do the oposite.. (note the exclamation mark before preg_match)

```
if ( !preg_match('/^[\-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/', $str) ) {
   $this->form_validation->set_message('decimalcustom', 'The %s field is required in 0.00 format.');
   return FALSE;
}
else {
   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I add allow null/blank to this statement? It's throwing the error if the form is blank, even though I don't have 'required' set.

Comment: I am not sure about the regex but you can simply do:
   ( !preg_match('/^[\-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/', $str) || empty($str))